# Deleted old key, create new Google Maps v2 API Key, now map won't show

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I changed my package structure in my app so I thought I needed to create a new API Key for my v2 maps, so I deleted the old one in Google, recreated a new one, and now my new app won't show the map, but my old app with the old package structure and API Key (that is still deployed on my phone) still works - how is that possible that the old API Key that I deleted still works to draw a map?

thanks

Comment: Did you try to clean the project and delete the app from your phone then reinstall it? This solved this issue for me once.

Comment: You also updated the API key in the manifest file, right?

Comment: Are you changed your package name in manifest file or else in normal java package?